# opencv_ffmpeg2413_64.dll Linux build for OpenCV

Tags: java, linux, opencv, ffmpeg

I am using opencv2413 for image processing and camera capture. My code runs fine on windows where i used windows build of opencv. With opencv you have to dynamically load some dll's such as `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_ffmpeg2413_64");` however, when i use the same code on Linux with Java7 its complains because of DLLs. I am looking for replacement which i found for  `Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME` the SO file but i cant find for`opencv_ffmpeg2413_64.dll`. Any advice how create/find that SO or do i have to change it to different library for camera capture? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. You don't need SO for ffmpeg,. All you have to do is create a build from the source on Linux. Install ffmpeg on the same machine.``` sudo apt-get update``sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ``` `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`Use *java -jar -Djava.library.path=""* to the compiled build/lib. You only need to `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` Make sure you have Aache Ant installed. Thats all.